# Long pause before loading my product thumbnails

Tags: seo, web-hosting, load-time, load-testing

I have a Wordpress website using WooCommerce, but my shop pages are really slow because it takes a very long time before my product thumbnails start to load. The page loads fine up till the moment that the product thumbnails (600px x 600px) should be fetched...

I have optimized these images & I'm using WP Rocket as caching plugin. However, in my example below, it takes about 67 seconds to load a page with only 5 thumbnails, which is really unacceptable.

Any idea on how to enhance my WooCommerce loading performance? I have attached the [GTMetrix report](http://www.filedropper.com/gtmetrix-report-bartoml215215axcnl-20171027t034923-vhswi9nt), where you can see the [waterfall diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vMl7.png).
There, you can see there is a long pause before the product images start to load. It's this pause I'd like to remove, but I don't know how...

Any idea?

Comment: Ok, so I think I have a clue. I have used a shortcode for Gravity Forms in the field which is my product description. I have disabled the product description excerpt on the product list pages, but it seems in the source code however, this Gravity forms shortcode is rendering in background. Every product has a shortcode behind it, so an enormous amount of Gravity Forms is rendered taking a very long time...

Comment: does this pause always happen before the images? You might want to check the webserver logs (example access_log if you're using apache) to see what's going on. Its likely that others are requesting content at the same time which creates the pauses and/or the web browser you are testing with isn't optimized either.

Answer (score 1):

Solution here: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284164/remove-product-description-from-product-archive-page/284171#284171

This was related to the template I was using, so not really webhost related.